# Check if a point lies on a line vector

Tags: vector, line, point

To get another point (`r`) on the line that passes through point `p` in the direction `v` we can use the following formula, and substitute any value for `a`:

[image: r = p + a*v]

To test if `r` is on the line, we must only find a value for `a` that satisfies. In my current implementation, I check if `a` is the same for each component of the vectors by reorganizing the equation for `r` to:

[image: a = px - rx / vx]

In code terms, this looks like the following:

```
boolean isPointOnLine(Vector2f r, Vector2f p, Vector2f v) {
    return (p.x - r.x) / v.x == (p.y - r.y) / v.y; 
}
```

However, this method does not work: If any component of `v` is `0`, the fraction will evaluate to infinity. Hence we get an incorrect result.

How do I check if `r` is on the line correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In 3D** you do the following:

If a point **`r=(x,y,z)`** is on the line with **`p=(px,py,pz)`** another point on the line and **`v=(vx,vy,vz)`** the direction calculate the following

```
CROSS(v,r-p)=0
```

or by component

```
(py-ry)*vz - (pz-rz)*vy==0
(pz-rz)*vx - (px-rx)*vz==0
(px-rx)*vy - (py-ry)*vx==0
```

For the **2D** version, make all *z*-components zero

```
(px-rx)*vy - (py-ry)*vx == 0
```

No division needed, no edge cases and simple fast multiplication.

Of course due to round-off the result will be never be exactly zero. So what you need is a formula for the minimum distance, and a check if the distance is within some tolerance

```
d = abs((px-rx)*vy-(py-ry)*vx)/sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy) <= tol
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the equation I had was in fact correct, the division by 0 is just an edge case that must be handled beforehand. The final function looks like this:

```
boolean isPointOnLine(Vector2f r, Vector2f p, Vector2f v) {
    if (v.x == 0) {
        return r.x == p.x;
    }
    if (v.y == 0) {
        return r.y == p.y;
    }
    return (p.x - r.x) / v.x == (p.y - r.y) / v.y; 
}
```